# How to load resources or assets in GLWallpaper service

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper

I am trying to develop an Android  live wallpaper **using `OpenGL` wallpaper service** , I am able to create live wallpaper  as in this [example](https://github.com/markfguerra/GLWallpaperExample) by Mark F Guerra But I want to add some sprite animation to my wallpaper.

I have already created a `OpenGL ES` sprite animation in another project. I just want to recreate my animation in the live wallpaper project.

But in my live wallpaper project i am **not able to get `Context` and  load my images from assets or resources**

Any *suggestions or sample codes or link* about **loading resourses or asset files while using `glwallpaper` service** will be very helpfull.

All suggestions and/or sample codes are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the context as shown below..

```
in wallpaper service class: 
------------------- 
renderer = new GlRenderer(this); 

in renderer class: 
---------------- 
private Context context; 

public GlRenderer(Context context) { 
this.context = context;
```

Instead of `this` we can use `getAssets()` or `getResources()` as parameter  to renderer .
On using `getAssets()` you can get the files saved in assets folder and by using `getResources()` you can get the files placed inside the resources folder in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the context from your engine to your renderer.  Then, here's some sample code to load the asset.  i.e. resourceID is your R.drawable.xxx bitmap.  I have this inside a texture atlas class I made, so a few things might not be completely contained in the method.  For example the options I might use to load the bitmap would include inscaled = false, but whatever works for you.   I also modified this to remove my error handling for instance.

```
/**
 * Load the resource and push it to the gpu memory, setup default values
 * @param gl
 * @param context
 * @param resourceID
 * @return glTextureID
 * 
 */
public int loadFromContext(GL10 gl, Context context, int resourceID) {
    mResourceID = resourceID;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceID, sBitmapOptions);
    sourceWidth = bmp.getWidth();
    sourceHeight = bmp.getHeight();
    gl.glGenTextures(1, mGLTextures, 0);
    mGLTextureID = mGLTextures[0];

    // bind and set min and mag scaling to bilinear
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGLTextureID);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    // repeat by default
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

    // upload bmp to video memory
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

    // check error
    int error = gl.glGetError();
    if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        // cleanup
        bmp.recycle();
        bmp = null;
        mLoaded = false;
            // error handling here
    } else {

        // unbind.
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        bmp.recycle();
        bmp = null;
        mLoaded = true;
        mDirty = true;

      } 
      return mGLTextureID;
}
```